# 'flushend' vs 'balance' for two-column balancing - what's the difference?

Tags: packages, two-column

There are (at least) two packages you can use to balance a two-column document's column length on the last page: `balance` and `flushend`.

Other than the superficial difference of `balance` requiring an explicit `\balance` command to be invoked - what are the differences between these two packages? Why was the later package (`flushend`) conceived when the earlier one exists?

Comment: Balance:  In order to balance the columns on a page, \balance must be given  somewhere within the first column. To turn off the feature, give   \nobalance. One has to look at the unbalanced text first to decide  where best to place \balance.

Comment: Flushend: Balanced columns on last page in twocolumn mode.

Comment: @Saravanan Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5817/1340. (La)TeX doesn't support a robust way to do the task. Neither package always works, and flushend can also make lines overlap sometimes.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: It's a related question, not a duplicate. If you could describe how the packages act different in different situations, that would be a good answer for this question - though perhaps not so much for the other one.

Answer (score 3):

An important difference between the two packages is in the **handling of footnotes** on the last page.  Neither shines at the job, but `flushend` issues a decent result when `balance`'s is incomprehensible.  I think It's better to use the former.

The same two pages using the two packages.  First with `flusheend`.

[image]
[image]

Second with `balance`.

[image]
[image]

The code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=105pt, bottom=75pt, left=75pt, right=75pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{flushend}
% \usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{A twocolumn document}
\author{flushend}
% \author{balance}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]


 
\section{Using either \texttt{balance} or \texttt{flushend}}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{thm}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{thm}

\lipsum[4]

Consider the following drawing\footnote{\lipsum[21]}.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick, fill=blue!50] (0, 0) rectangle (3, 8);
    \draw[thick, fill=orange!70, rotate=10] (0, 0) rectangle (3, 8);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Rectangles and colors}
  \label{fig:rc}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

% \balance

As a consequence, we have\footnote{Well, well!  It appears in an
  unexpected place.}

\begin{lem}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```